# How to slide up text fields in summary band when one is empty?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a *JasperReports* report for an Invoice. At the bottom of the Invoice in the *Summary* Band, I have a few fields which are summed from the Invoice details. Standard stuff. One of the fields will be a "Account Balance", which lists any outstanding balance on the account so I can add it to the "Amount Due Today" which is the last line of the *Summary* Section.

However, most accounts don't have an outstanding balance so I'd like to skip the line on those invoices, but move the below text fields up.

How can I accomplish this? Using latest version of *JasperReports* and use the *Groovy* engine. I'm thinking I could somehow programmatically change the position of some elements, or perhaps use a *subreport* for the summary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood, the "line" "account balance" is a simple text field?
Then just set the option **"Remove line When Blank"** and possibly **"Blank When Null"** to remove the  field if it´s empty.

The following elements should have the **"float"** setting, as Israel mentioned.

Comment: That did work. Since I have an accompanying label field as well, I was able to add a print when expression of $V{Account Balance} != 0 and then set the fields below to float. This achieved exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

For stuff like this I end up being a bit creative and create separate 1px height table elements/text-fields.  Then you can set these element's position anchor to "float" and stack them on top of another, and expand on overflow flag to true.  So when they populate or their print when is true, it will expand and display as normal.

Comment: Float was certainly the trick for this (along with Print When Expression). What exactly would the overflow flag do for me here?

Comment: I use the Overflow Flag and 1px high elements so I can compress elements into a smaller space to avoid having a larger band.  For example on a detail band I may need to call a Table to execute if a Field is not null. If I have my table element at 20px height, the detail band will need to be big enough to accommodate -always-. Setting the height to 1px and overflow flag allows me to "hide" elements, since if my Field is null, it only took up 1px.  Having multiple detail bands with print when expressions would be better, but this technique works in other situations too.

Comment: I hate this kind of creativity, but seems that this is the only way.